# PHP File/PDF Streaming and Safari Crashing

Tags: php, file, safari, php-7.4

From reading around this seems like a Safari bug and/or a common issue with Safari but i've yet to find a solid answer to this. Also, apologies for the long thread.

So i have a simple PHP script (no framework used) that does a DB lookup on a unique ID, returns the PDF filename and path and then streams the file using readfile() -

```php
// Get file ID from route
$fileID = $routeMatch['params']['id'];

// Lookup file details
$dbConn = ...PDO connection...
// Query
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT
              `files`.`path`,
              `files`.`filename`
            FROM `files`
            WHERE
              `files`.`id` = :fileid
            LIMIT 1;';
// Prepare + Binds
$dbStmt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$dbStmt->bindParam(':fileid', $fileID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
// Execute
try {
  $dbStmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  exit('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$fileRow = $dbStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Check if file exists in table
if (!$fileRow || count($fileRow) <= 0) exit();

// Full path to file
$fileFullPath = $fileRow['path'] . $fileRow['filename'];

// Check file exists and readable
if (!@file_exists($fileFullPath) || !@is_readable($fileFullPath)) exit();

// Headers
header('Accept-Ranges: none');
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($fileFullPath));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileFullPath));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $fileRow['filename'] . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fileFullPath)) . ' GMT');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 86400) . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');

// Stream & Exit
readfile($fileFullPath);
exit();
```

And then i have a HTML file with a number of links that use JS to dynamically create/re-create an Object tag (have tried embed and iframe tags; results are the same) to display the PDF document (all below 3/4MB in size).

And this is all hosted on a very vanilla LAMP stack (cPanel hosting; HTTP2 disabled).

This works perfectly in a Mozilla or a Chromium browser but, after selecting a few links within Safari (using v16.5 but have tried older versions), it will crash the tab.
You can open new tabs and navigate to other websites but trying to load the same website in a new tab result in Safari hanging on loading and the only way out is to restart Safari.
No error messages are displayed in the console.

So i have noticed with Safari, which other browsers don't appear to be doing, is that it creates multiple connections to the same PHP script with it dropping (at least) one connection after only a few kb -
[image: Safari multiple connections]

And when another PDF link is clicked on and displayed, Safari attempts to create a third connection requesting the file but with the 'Range' header (assume it's a partial request), at which point it throws an error and hangs the tab -
[image: Safari range connection]

Below are the request and response headers within Safari -
[image: Safari request response]
[image: Safari request response]
[image: Safari request Range header]

I suspect this is a bug with Safari but, what's the reason for Safari creating multiple connections and requests to the same file where other browsers are only creating one?

Secondly, with setting the 'Accept-Ranges' header to 'none', my assumption is that browsers should *not* attempt partial requests.
*If* Safari is throwing an error whilst attempting to partially request a PDF file, is it simply ignoring the 'Accept-Ranges' header when it shouldn't be (aka it's a bug)?

And *if* Safari is attempting a partial request, am i right in thinking that dealing with the 'Range' header (stream only requested bytes of the file) within the PHP script would mostly likely solve this?
Or am i completely barking up the wrong tree and the actual reason and solution to this is something completely different?

I've been going back and forth with this error with Safari for a while, read endless posts and threads and i'm completely baffled; so any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks all :)

**Edit** - <strike>After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337958/serverhttp-range-returns-null-every-time) post, the PDFY code and with a bit of of trial and error, i ended up adding (nothing else) -</strike>

```php
// Safari ultra crude 'fix'
$range = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'];
} elseif (function_exists("apache_request_headers")) {
    $apache_headers = apache_request_headers();
    if (isset($apache_headers['Range']) && !empty($apache_headers['Range'])) $range = $apache_headers['Range'];
    if (isset($apache_headers['range']) && !empty($apache_headers['range'])) $range = $apache_headers['range'];
}
if ($range !== false) http_status_code(206);
```

Which essentially throws a '206' HTTP code if the 'Range' header exists in the request.
Safari still throws an error and still requests multiple connections but it stops the tab from hanging.

So i imagine Safari, by default, uses multiple connections when requesting a file to help with download speeds and therefore *is* doing partial requests. But i thought 'Accept-Ranges: none' *should* prevent that happening.
Ignore the above - this stopped Safari hanging but as 'http_status_code' isn't a PHP function, it threw errors. Changing it to 'http_response_code' resulted in the browser/tab hanging again.
So it seemed the script throwing an error seemed to have prevented the browser hanging which doesn't make sense...at all!

**Edit 2** - After spending a few more days on this it seems this issue is caused by Safari attempting to byte-range (or content-range/partial-range/partial download/chunk etc) the file.
Apple's own documentation, [Configuring Your Server HTTP](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6), seems to suggest Safari *should* only do this to media files (it will ignore the 'Accept-Ranges' header) but, it appears Safari completely ignores this (bug perhaps?) and the `Accept-Ranges: none` header (which from what i've read *should* prevent byte-range happening any way) regardless of file type and attempts to byte-range PDF (seen it with DOC/DOCX files too) files over 1/2MB.
It's still a complete mystery what causes Safari (/a tab) to hang though and i can only suspect this is a bug with Safari itself.

Currently i've added a load of lines to try and handle the 'RANGE' header Safari requests which seems to be working. Albeit, Safari still creates multiple connections for the file, with and without the 'RANGE' header (no idea why), and still throws an error relating to the connection with a 'RANGE' header.
Safari/tab doesn't crash though.
I will try and post an answer after testing this bodge "fix" some more.

But i'm still open to any ideas or information on how to handle this properly, especially a (nice and simple) library, as my fix is a bandaid at best and i can see it failing.

Much appreciate the help so far though :-)

Comment: I would start by expiring the streamed PDF instantly, and also not cache, although I doubt that this would solve the problem since this should only affect a wholly downloaded file. Does the same PDF work fine when you access the file directly from Safari through the webserver? Just to test whether it's the streaming through PHP that causes this problem.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I'll try expiring the cache and see how i get on. And yes, if the PDF files are in a 'public' directory, Safari accesses them perfectly fine.
Just to add a bit more context, i've ten 'test' PDF links/files and it doesn't matter which PDF is selected, the first PDF will display fine (albeit it does two connections), click a second link and it'll display (again two connections) but Safari requests the file for a third time with the 'Range' header, throws an error and hangs the tab. At which point you have to restart Safari to visit the page again.

Comment: Where does the `$fileID` come from? I'm asking this because I'm wondering about the URL of the PHP file that streams the PDFs. Preferably each PDF should have an unique URL, which can, for instance, be done with a parameter: `https://example.com/getPDF.php?fileId=34`. Browsers can ignore any header you send.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I probably should have made that clearer in the post but essentially i use a router class, so '/file/' routes to the PHP script and the file id is a parameter of that, eg- '/file/2e391c019f8be9ad554db2420', the unique file id is '2e391c019f8be9ad554db2420' and that's what i do a lookup on.

Comment: I have seen this post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337958/serverhttp-range-returns-null-every-time)) which references PDFY and code used to handle the 'Range' requested header.
I am wondering if i implement something similar then that would solve the issue but, it still doesn't answer why Safari is opening multiple connections nor why it's attempting to partial request the file, if that *is* what it is doing.
As you can tell, i am completely baffled by it all.